# How to make a Spring API to be a public webservice accessible through Internet?

Tags: spring, web-services

I need to create a Spring `webservice`. It should be public, accessible through Internet. How to make that possible ? And how to annotate the class and method involved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your application on some PaaS provider like heroku or PCF.

For Spring boot for RESTful APIs. Annotations should be @RestController, @GetMapping, @PostMapping....

To accept params
@RequestParam and @PathVariable

Comment: is heroku free ? and PCF ?

Comment: Yes, but with limited features. If you just need to deploy basic service I think you will be good.

Comment: How is the webservice called ? and how are parameters provided through the call ?

Comment: You can use tools like SOAP UI or Postman to call the service and for parameters I have added in answer. You can pass paramters either as query param or Path Variable with in URL.

Comment: I dont understand but is it like passing URL parameters `www.someName.com?param1=value1` ?